# Appropriateness in requesting the manager to include me in a formal conversation with a potential vendor

Tags: colleagues, career-development

I recently discovered an OEM which develops hardware that solves many of the problems which my team is facing. I am sending the details to my manager. I am closely involved in this project and would like to be involved in the formal discussions with the OEM.

Would it be OK to request my manager, if he considers pursuing this direction, to include me in the conversation? He usually does not do that. In fact, this is not a culture in my team. People pursue directions individually even if the ideas come through collaboration.

Note: I am only 3 months into the job.

Comment: You won't know until you ask! I personally think it is okay to make such request.

Comment: What level are you, senior?

Comment: I am a senior scientist. @Kilisi ( If I become a manager, ever, I would prefer a flat hierarchy.)

Comment: **Would it be OK to request my manager, if he considers pursuing this direction, to include me in the conversation?** - Why wouldn't it be OK to ask? They're either going to say yes or no. Either way, there's no harm in the asking.

Comment: Yes, ask. senior scientist should be trusted to know when to maintain discretion in such discussions, if the business situation calls for that. Speaking as engr/tech lead from the other side of this type of situation, IMO the chances of project success go up the earlier you become involved.

Comment: `He usually does not do that.` - You mention that you are 3 months into your job. How can you know what he "usually" does in this short a time?

Comment: @joel etherton long enough time for this to happen 3-4 times.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a downside to asking. It makes sense to have experts involved although not all companies work like that.

There are valid business reasons for keeping suppliers and employees at arms length. It's less efficient in some ways but a good idea in others. So don't be overly disappointed if it doesn't eventuate.

I'm not sure how to rate your chances. You're a senior scientist so there will be respect for your specific knowledge, but you're also a new hire so that is a factor. If normal policy is against it, I would expect a refusal all things considered. You haven't given any reasoning I can see why they would make an exception in this case. But nothing to stop you asking, you'll either be pleasantly surprised or mildly disappointed.